# Any Spanish speech variety where F is pronounced as ϕ?

Tags: spanish, fricatives, bilabial

Are there any living speech varieties of Spanish (geographic, socio-economic) that pronounce the phoneme associated with the letter 'f' as [ϕ], as bilabial rather than labiodental?  Just wondering since when I look at the Spanish consonants, /f/ looks like pretty much the only labiodental as opposed to bilabial /p/, while /θ/ and /t/ are both dental and /x/ and /k/ are both velar.

Also, the book [*From Latin to Spanish: Historical phonology and morphology of the Spanish Language* by Paul M. Lloyd](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=oSzzpvHCLT0C&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q&f=false) speculated about Early Latin 'f' being pronounced as [ϕ] in free variation or geographic variation with [f] in the Iberian peninsula.

EDIT:
In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_phonology#Consonants) as well, it says "A common pronunciation of /f/ in nonstandard speech is the voiceless bilabial fricative [ɸ], so that fuera is pronounced [ˈɸweɾa] rather than [ˈfweɾa].", but didn't specified which nonstandard speech.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: By saying /ϕ/, do you mean the same sound as in Japanese *fu*?

Comment: @user3503: I'm wondering as well. Would have been more helpful if there was an explanation.

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, bilabial voiceless fricative.

Comment: Well, Spanish do pronounce the V as a bilabial, rather than a labiodental, so while I'm inclined to say no on the spot to your core question — I've been studying/speaking Spanish for a while and never noticed it —, I'd like to see if something comes up. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I don't get your response. I do know that both letters B and V get pronounced as bilabial in all contexts. But my question is about F, not V?

Comment: @Alenanno: In English the letters F and V are both labiodentals, while in Spanish the letter V is bilabial. Does that extends to the letter F? If yes, which dialects or sociolects?

Comment: @Noble_Bright_Life Yes, but what I meant is that, if it happens in that context, it's not absurd to wonder if it happens somewhere else. :D

Comment: @Alenanno: Pardon me for being slow, but what does "it" refers to in "it happens in that context" and "it happens somewhere else"? Looks like they mean different. Also, when you say "somewhere", do you mean (a) other languages apart from Spanish, (b) other dialects of Spanish, or (c) other sounds within a Spanish dialect?

Comment: @Noble_Bright_Life I mean that if Spanish has a sound which is bilabial, when most if not all other european languages have labiodental (v), then it might have other exceptions in a similar fashion, like the one you described.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### /f/ as [ϕ] in Andean, Palenquero, Caribbean, Puerto Rican Spanish

[**The Linguistics of Spanish** - Andean Spanish - 2. Pronunciation](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/andeanr.htm#f)

> **2.4 Pronunciation of /f/**
>   /f/ is commonly articulated as a voiceless bilabial fricative (symbol: [ɸ]):
>
> - `[ˈɸɾuta]` *fruta* ‘fruit’
>
> An epenthetic [w] is often inserted between [ɸ] and a following vowel:
>
> - `[ɸwaˈmilja]` *familia* ‘family’

[**The Atlas of Pidgin and Creole Language Structures Online**](http://apics-online.info/sentences/48-221) <sup>[2](http://apics-online.info/parameters/187#2/25.5/-11.3)</sup>

> ɸ - voiceless bilabial fricative
>
> Palenquero | Exists only as a minor allophone | Spanish
>
> In words like *fue* 'be', *fuego* 'fire' and *fuette* 'strong' the bilabial fricative /f/ is common, and reflects dialectal variation in (rural) Spanish.

[**Dialect Density in Bilingual Puerto Rican Spanish-English Speaking Children**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4084752/)

> On the other hand, dialect features of Puerto Rican Spanish, such as the substitution of /ʃ/ for /ʧ/, /ŋ/ for /n/, or /ɸ/ for /f/ do not involve substituting a less complex sound for a more complex sound, as they are relatively similar in complexity ([Jakobson, 1968](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4084752/#R24)).

[***Los sonidos del español:*** Spanish Language edition](https://books.google.es/books?id=bzYUAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=%C9%B8), By José Ignacio Hualde

> [image]

[**The Handbook of Hispanic Linguistics**](https://books.google.es/books?id=U9CL4xNpZXwC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=%C9%B8), edited by José Ignacio Hualde, Antxon Olarrea, Erin O'Rourke

> [image]

---

### /sb/ as [ϕ] in Andalusian Spanish

[**Wikipedia** - Fonología del español](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol#Sonidos_conson%C3%A1nticos):

> El sonido de [*[ɸ]](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_labial_sorda) aparece en español de Andalucía como alófono de /B/ (*b, v*) después de *-s*:
>
> - *de**sb**aratar* > [deɸaɾa'ta]
> - *lo**s b**uenos* > [lɔ ɸwenɔ]
>
> Y también ocasionalmente en secuencias como *clu**bs**, o**bs**curo, su**bs**tancia* en ciertas variedades.

[**Wikipedia** - Andalusian Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_Spanish#Phonological_features)

> In Andalusian and Murcian Spanish syllable-final /s/ is very unstable; often assimilated to [ɸ] before /b/ (/sb/ → [hβ] → [hɸ] → [ɸː]), as in
>
> - *desbaratar* → **effaratar* [ɛhɸaɾaˈta]~[ɛɸːaɾaˈta] ('to ruin, to disrupt')
>
> or to [ɹ] (where ceceo or distinción occur) before /θ/ (/sθ/ → [ɹθ]), as in *ascensor* [aɹθẽ̞nˈso̞] ('lift').

[**The Linguistics of Spanish** - Andalusian Spanish - 2. Pronunciation](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/andalusir.htm#2)

> #### 2.2 Consonantal weakening
>
> Syllable-final `/s/` may be realized as `[h]` (as in `[ehpaɲa]` *España*), it may be elided (as in `[laola]` *las olas* ‘the waves’), or there may be a process of assimilation vis-à-vis the following consonant. When the following consonant is a voiceless obstruent or a sonorant, the output of the process is usually a geminate, as in `[eloβippo]` *el obispo* ‘the bishop’ or `[mimmo]` *mismo* ‘same’. With voiced obstruents, on the other hand, the output is usually a single (voiceless) consonant: `[laxaʝinah]` *las gallinas* ‘the hens’, `[laɸolah]` *las bolas* ‘the balls’.

---

### Misc.

[**Wikipedia** - Voiceless bilabial fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bilabial_fricative)

> [image]
>
> <sup>**4.** Boyd-Bowman, Peter (1953), "Sobre la pronunciación del español en el Ecuador", *Nueva Revista de Filología Hispánica*</sup>
>   <sup>**5.** Cotton, Eleanor Greet; Sharp, John (1988), [*Spanish in the Americas*](https://books.google.com/books?id=89KX2RC6Gx0C)</sup>
>   <sup>**6.** Wetzels, W. Leo; Mascaró, Joan (2001), ["The Typology of Voicing and Devoicing"](http://ruccs.rutgers.edu/~prince/hold/wetzels-mascaro.pdf), *Language*</sup>
>   <sup>**7.** [Coda obstruents and local constraint conjunction
>   in north-central Peninsular Spanish](http://roa.rutgers.edu/files/383-0300/383-0300-MORRIS-0-1.PDF)</sup>
>   <sup>**8.** Pérez, Ramón Morillo-Velarde; Aguilar, Rafael Cano; Jiménez, Antonio Narbona (1998), *El Español hablado en Andalucía*</sup>

[**Wikipedia** - Transcripción fonética del español con el AFI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripci%C3%B3n_fon%C3%A9tica_del_espa%C3%B1ol_con_el_AFI#cite_note-b-2)

> En el dialecto andaluz, murciano, manchego y canario y también en las Antillas hispanohablantes la aproximante [β̞] se puede tornar fricativa sorda [ɸ] cuando va precedida de /s/ aspirada, [ʰ]; *desbordar* [dɛʰɸo̞ɾˈð̞a̠ɾ]~[dɛʰɸo̞ð̞ˈð̞a̠(ɾ)].

> /f/ se pronuncia bilabial [ɸ], como la *f* de la romanización del japonés (Rōmaji). Es oído en algunas zonas aisladas de España y sobre todo en la América andina; *fuera* [ˈɸwe̞ɾa̠].

---

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is at least one to my knowledge. I have read (and heard) about this realisation of the phoneme. The variety that is commonly mentioned is Andean Spanish, and for this allophone, the main locations where it has been registered are some regions of Venezuela, Colombia, and Ecuador.